# Remove Deleted files from visual studio solution

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-sdk

Is there any way in the visual studio 2010 SDK to remove a file that doesn't exist on disk.
I've tried using the [VCProject.RemoveReference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.removereference.aspx) and the [VCProject.RemoveFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.vcprojectengine.vcproject.removefile) methods, but both reqiure an Object to be passed. The problem I'm finding is I can't create a file object from a file that doesn't exist on disk.
Is there another way to delete the reference from the project?

Comment: Are we only talking at runtime?

Comment: Yep. So in an extension, when a file is deleted from disk, I'd like to remove the reference from my project